# Doctrine new property/column definition not working

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have added new properties to a doctrine as below:

```
/** @Column(type="string", length=150) **/
private $service_domain;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=150) **/
private $aauid;
```

Added getter/setter properties:

```
public function getServiceDomain() {

    return $this->service_domain;
}

public function setServiceDomain($domain) {
    $this->service_domain = $domain;
    return $this;
}

    public function getAAUID() {

    return $this->aauid;
}

public function setAAUID($aauid) {
    $this->aauid = $aauid;
    return $this;
}
```

I also made the respective change in database column as well.
[image]

But for some strange reason, when I am assigning value to these properties and saving the entity, all other properties are saving except my new added ones:

```
$n->setServiceDomain("test");
$n->setAAUID("test");
```

Can you please clarify if I am doing anything wrong or do I have to make change in any other sections as well? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute is missing in your column definition

```
/** @Column(name="service_domain", type="string", length=150) **/
private $service_domain;

/** @Column(name="aauid", type="string", length=150) **/
private $aauid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, if name doesn't provided, then variable name is being considered as column name. Also, I figured out it worked well after I restarted the LAMP server. so, not exactly sure why it wasn't working at first time. May be doctrine did still referencing to old db schema. Thanks.